# We want to hide some accumatica screen from site map while published our customization package

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We want to hide some acumatica screen from site map while published our customization package.

For this I have Write code in master data Plugin its working fine for single tenant but in case of multiple tenant it's not working.

I am Getting error
PX.Data.PXLockViolationException
Message "Error: Another process has updated the 'MUIScreen' record. Your changes will be lost." string

Below is code:--

SiteMapMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance();
List siteNodeList = EWPMMasterDataHelper.GetSiteNodesData();

foreach(EWPMSiteMapDTO siteNodeDTO in siteNodeList) {

```
foreach(PX.SiteMap.DAC.SiteMap siteMap in PXSelect<PX.SiteMap.DAC.SiteMap,
 Where<PX.SiteMap.DAC.SiteMap.screenID, Equal<Required<PX.SiteMap.DAC.SiteMap.screenID>>>>.Select(graph, siteNodeDTO.ScreenID)) {

    // Check Screen is exits on site node or not.
    if(siteMap != null && (siteMap.Workspaces == ProductionOrderworkSpaceID.ToString() || siteMap.Workspaces == BillOfMaterialWorkSpaceID.ToString())) {
        siteMap.Workspaces = emptyWorkSpaceID.ToString();
        graph.SiteMap.Update(siteMap);
    }
}
```

}
graph.Actions.PressSave();